# No Data Fetched From Firebase in Cell In UiTableViewCell Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Hi guys i am stuck in a problem and couldnt find a solution anywhere .Can anyone tell me whats the issue, i have just started learning swift I want to fetch data from my firebase database and print it on the uitableviewcell

I have created a swift file which has

class Categories: NSObject {
    var categories : String?
    }

my Viewcontroller is below

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var categoryList = [Categories]()


    var refHandle:UInt!
    var ref:FIRDatabaseReference?

    @IBOutlet weak var listOfCategories: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuBtn: UIBarButtonItem!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        menuBtn.target = revealViewController()
        menuBtn.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

        fetchCategories()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categoryList.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        // Set cell content
        cell.textLabel?.text = categoryList[indexPath.row].categories

    return cell


    }

    func fetchCategories(){

        refHandle = ref?.child("Categories").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                print(dictionary)

                let categories = Categories()



                categories.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                self.categoryList.append(categories)

                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                   self.listOfCategories.reloadData()
                }

            }
        })

    }


}
```

My Database

```
-Categories
  -name
    Bikes:"Bikes"
    Cars:"Cars"
    Cats:"Cats"
```

if i print(categorList) i dont get it on the console too.. Below is the log

> 2017-04-06 06:09:50.531 Wallpapers App[1716] 
>   [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.3700000 started
>   2017-04-06 06:09:50.534 Wallpapers App[1716] 
>   [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the
>   following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see
>   http://goo . gl/RfcP7r) 2017-04-06 06:09:50.565 Wallpapers App[1716]
>    [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003007] Successfully created
>   Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the
>   proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the
>   Info.plist 2017-04-06 06:09:50.580 Wallpapers App[1716] 
>   [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not
>   currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more
>   at http://goo. gl/9vSsPb 2017-04-06 06:09:50.589 Wallpapers App[1716]
>    [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
>   ["Cars": Cars, "Bikes": Bikes, "Cats": Cats] 2017-04-06 06:09:52.565
>   Wallpapers App[1716:28745] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key Cars.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104725d4b **exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000103d6621e objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000104725c99 -[NSException raise] + 9   3   Foundation
>
>   0x00000001038749df -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] +
>   291   4   Foundation                          0x00000001038d672f
>   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:] + 301   5   Wallpapers App                      0x00000001026fe886
>   _TFFC14Wallpapers_App14ViewController15fetchCategoriesFT_T_U_FCSo15FIRDataSnapshotT_
>   + 1126    6   Wallpapers App                      0x00000001026fed8c _TTRXFo_oCSo15FIRDataSnapshot__XFdCb_dS_** + 60  7   Wallpapers App                      0x00000001027c85b0 **63-[FIRDatabaseQuery
>   observeEventType:withBlock:withCancelBlock:]_block_invoke + 37    8
>
>   Wallpapers App                      0x00000001027efeb3
>   __43-[FChildEventRegistration fireEvent:queue:]_block_invoke.68 + 88  9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107470978
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12     10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010749a0cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8     11  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x000000010747a8a4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 406    12 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001046e9e49
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001046af37d __CFRunLoopRun
>   + 2205    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001046ae884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420   15  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000109439a6f GSEventRunModal + 161  16  UIKit
>   0x000000010525cc68 UIApplicationMain + 159    17  Wallpapers App
>   0x0000000102701fcf main + 111     18  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00000001074e668d start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the method

```
setValuesForKeys
```

This method description says that:

```
Sets properties of the receiver with values from a given dictionary, using its keys to identify the properties.
```

And your error says, that your category class is not key-value compliant with the key "Cars", because there is no key/property named "Cars" in your "Categories" class.

From what I see, you are trying to print all these categories in a UITableViewCell. I would suggest changing your Categories class to the following:

```
struct Category() {
    var key: String
    var value: String
}
```

Post that, when you get the response in fetchCategories() method. Parse that dictionary:

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    let category = Category(key: key, value: value as! String)
    self.listOfCategories.append(category)
}
```

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath. You can set the text like so.

```
cell.textLabel?.text = categoryList[indexPath.row].value
```

You might want to simplify your Category struct if you just need the value in the response received from Firebase. Then your struct becomes a simple:

```
struct Category() {
    var name: String
}
```

I prefer using structs over classes wherever I can, but you can use a class if you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have two questions 
1)showing the data in the cell
2)printing the data so you can see it

I'll address 2) as I think once you see the data, you can work with it (at least that has been my experience - also being fairly new to Xcode)

Xcode is not 'simple' to print the data like we'd like.... (you will probably find it as frustrating as I have - coming from a JS/jQuery/PHP background)

What I find simplest is to use a plugin called "SimpleJSON" (there are others, this is the one I found suits my purpose) and take the data to a JSON package, where I can see the data (the whole idea, right?), then work on it as needed from there.

in the pod file, just add

```
import SwiftyJSON
```

then in your code where you want to see the data

```
let categoriesJSON = JSON(categories)
print(categoriesJSON)
```

from there, you will get a list to work with in an array

```
print(categoriesJSON["name"]["Cars"]
```

Not a completely 'Swift-y' solution, perhaps, but it gets the job done!